# Jquery Hide/show table cell for multiple tablecells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one table, which having 15 columns and around 2000+ records.
Now I want to hide/show last 5 columns. To do that I use following jQuery Statement.

```
    $("table.border-box td.disp").toggle();
```

td having "disp" class will hide/show table cells.

But this will result in Browser with following stop script error.

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

```
Script: http://localhost:8080/XXX/resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.js:4055
```

How can I optimize this and also solve browser error.(Browser: Mozilla Firefox:15.0)

Comment: Are you displaying all post on one site?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use pagination method to limit your records in the page or limit records with lazyloading contents.

Comment: Hello I have solved problem, instead of toggling td, I have toggles css. `$(".disp").css("display"," table-cell");` and `$(".disp").css("display"," none");`. it is working smoothly,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$("table.border-box").find(".disp").toggle();
```

Also cache it for using it another time, like this:

```
tds = $("table.border-box").find(".disp");//only do expensive operation once

tds.toggle();
...
...
tds.toggle();
```

as this way you will be avoiding the [performance penalty](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) of using `querySelectorAll()` which is used for complex selectors, better to nest simple ones like ".class" so jquery uses the more performance `getElementsByTagName()` internally.

Obviously if this is not enough you should refactor your code, like other answers suggests.

Answer (score 1):

code you have shared is perfectly fine.

i have created a JS Fiddle to test this: http://jsfiddle.net/3z7Ze/

Make sure your records are loaded completely before you are trying to show/hide columns. And there are no other scripts running at that time (which may conflict with show/hide functionality).

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys already mentioned you should split the result in multiple pages.
But if you can't do this, maybe another, yet not very nice, approach would be to iterate through each row manually and fire the toggle events asynchronously.